# Как показывать на странице по времени разные div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Искал давно способ как показывать на странице в одном div через определенное время, рекламу Google ? Скажем есть код рекламы

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-16111028515294758"
     data-ad-slot="5625238776"></ins>
```

И есть такой же код только другой рекламы. Как показывать по очередно эти коды ? Чтобы отображалась реклама на странице в одном месте. Скажем Сперва Google потом Яндекс и так через определенное время, скажем через 30 секунд менялись ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

```js
setInterval(() => {

  document.querySelectorAll('.ad div')
          .forEach(ad => ad.classList.toggle('hidden'))

}, 3000)
```

```css
.one, .two {
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  top:0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.one {
  background-color:green;
}

.two {
  background-color:red;
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ad">
  <div class="one">ad 1</div>
  <div class="two hidden">ad 2</div>
</div>

<div class="ad">
  <div class="one hidden">ad 3</div>
  <div class="two">ad 4</div>
</div>
```