# Показ баннеров через определенное время

Tags: php

Есть такой код на PHP который показывает заранее подготовленные страницы с баннером поочередно, но только когда страница загружается. Если страницу перезагрузить покажется другой баннер. Как сделать чтобы баннеры менялись без перезагрузки страницы, через заданное время.

```
    <?php
$banner = rand(1,3); 
include $banner.".html"; 
?>
```

Comment: выгрузите на страницу сразу все баннеры и подключите какой-нибудь слайдер, (например https://codepen.io/doodlemarks/pen/aFcly)

Comment: Вы конечно можете использовать `sleep`, если требуется сделать только на PHP https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php, но лучше как советует @Skywave подключить слайдер или же вывести сразу все баннеры и отображать посредством JS.

Comment: Тогда как мне сделать, надо чтобы один баннер сразу показывался, а второй и третий через определенное время. Как мне это все в коде изложить ?  Если так то тогда просто весь код через 10 секунд заработает, выполнится, не важно страница перезагрузилась или нет ?    
   <?php sleep(10);
$banner = rand(1,3); 
include $banner.".html"; 
?>

Comment: Потом у меня не картинки а страницы HTML в место банеров

Comment: Skywave тогда уже это по удачней будет 
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/978366/Как-показывать-на-странице-по-времени-разные-div/978375#978375 Мне на PHP надо потому что JS задержки большие, видно изменения, а PHP это все быстрее обрабатывает. Sleep как прописать чтобы код выполнялся через 10 секунд скажем, а не один раз ?